# Longitude and Latitude of polyline : Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is their a way to get latitude and longitude of polyline?

```
var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {      
    color: 'black',        
    opacity: 5,       
    smoothFactor: 1,    
    weight: 3,
})

map.addLayer(firstpolyline);
firstpolyline.getLatLng();
```

here firstpolyline is givng an error that "getLatLng() is not a function". I want to check if polyline is within the map bound or not like this

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
if(bounds.contains(firstpolyline.getLatLng())){
    ......
}
```

Comment: See http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#polyline-getlatlngs

Comment: also you should use code styling for future visitor of your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `getLatLngs()` function. So try this:

```
var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'black',
    opacity: 5,
    smoothFactor: 1,
    weight: 3,
})
map.addLayer(firstpolyline);
var arrayOfPoints = firstpolyline.getLatLngs();
```

Then you can easily iterate over an array of points and get latitude and logitude or check if point is in bounds of polygon.

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayOfPoints.length; i++) {
    if(map.getBounds().contains(arrayOfPoints[i])) {
        console.log('is in bounds');
    };
}
```